# How can I add roles to a Azure AD group in bicep format?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-bicep

I have a questions regarding "How can I add roles to a Azure AD group in bicep format"
Is it possible , i will not be able to do that .
If someone know ,please share with me

I have a Project to make it Possible by  BICEP Solution

I have a some groups in Azure ad & i have to make bicep file to make those groups to Owner & Contributor permission in Storage account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/scenarios-rbac#role-definition-id)

```
param principalId string

@description('This is the built-in Contributor role. See https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#contributor')
resource contributorRoleDefinition 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions@2018-01-01-preview' existing = {
  scope: subscription()
  name: 'b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c'
}

resource roleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = {
  name: guid(resourceGroup().id, principalId, contributorRoleDefinition.id)
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: contributorRoleDefinition.id
    principalId: principalId
    principalType: 'ServicePrincipal'
  }
}
```

Id for `Contributor` role is `b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c`, and for `Owner` it is `8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635`.

You just need to provide principal id for your AD groups.

Comment: Thanks for Info . I will tried that way & its working

Comment: Could you consider upvoting my reply and mark it as answer?